# New-FimImportObject is not recognized by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am not able to use `New-FimImportObject` command, it is not recognized by PowerShell.
Can someone tell me what the possible reasons are?
I am using PowerShell 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the module is not loaded and if you are running V3, it should have autoloaded if the module was in its proper location:

```
($Env:PSModulePath -split ';')[0]
```

You should make sure that the module is placed in this path so it can provide the functions you need to use.

You can also check for all of the available modules by running this:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```